# Counter automata with a bound on the counters?

Tags: automata, reference-request

It is widely known that the emptiness of counter automata is undecidable since two counters are enough to simulate a Turing machine (see the classic book from Hopcroft and Ullman, for example).

However, what happens if we put a bound $k$ on the values stored by the counters? In this restricted model, the counters cannot be incremented more than $k$.

I think this makes the problem decidable, is this correct? And in this case, what is the complexity? Is there any reference about this problem?

Comment: If the counters are bounded, you can get rid of them by including them as part of the set of states.

Comment: Yes, this makes it easy to prove membership in PSPACE, I suppose. But what about the hardness?

Comment: Can you define the model more precisely?

Answer (score 2):

If the counters are bounded by $k$, then the number of possible states is finite, so this is a finite-state machine, and emptiness for finite-state machines is decidable.  In particular, if there are $c$ counters, each bounded by $k$, then there are $O(k^c)$ states, so emptiness can be tested in $O(k^c)$ time.

Assuming the automaton allows nondeterminism, it is easy to prove that the problem is NP-hard, by a reduction from 3SAT.  (Store the value of $x_i$ in the $i$th counter, selecting its value nondeterministically, then scan over the formula, checking each clause to see if it holds.)